# How can we track number of devices using our Android app after being preloaded by multiple partners?

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-play, google-play-developer-api

We have and Android app and we ought to distribute it through some of our partners and will be pre-loaded on those devices.

At the same time we need to keep accountability of how many devices, for each partner, is using our app.

Once the we release a new app version those devices might or might not be updated and we require to still keep accountability over how many devices for each partner is using our app.

We have been told to add a `"channel code"` to our app but we don't think that can be done as once the app is updated that channel code would be lost. Also, that would imply having to distribute "different .apk's" (or customised apk's) and that is something we want to avoid at all costs.

We can use Google Analytics however will not give us accurate numbers as GA would also include the devices that have installed our app through Google Play.

Therefore, any help explaining us how can we add that tracking mechanism would be very much appreciated.

Comment: We have been told we can add a channel code on the meta-data block of the Android Manifest. That "could work", however we have read the Manifest is overwritten on app updates unless your pre-installed app has special permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested on knowing the number of devices using your app at any moment, and the total usages over time GA is a good way to go. You need only to create a GA session at application start as in:[GA session management](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/sessions?hl=es).

Note that before that you should get and configure you GA account as in: [GA account for real time events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638637).

Comment: Thanks @crigore for your reply. We're already doing that. The thing here is that we want to know those numbers but separating our partners that are preloading our app and using the same apk for all of them (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that met the point, but i track the devices by sending the DeviceID on every start of my app.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String txtguid =  tm.getDeviceId();
```

I use a predefined URL to send the DeviceID and some additional informations (Version Code, timestamp etc) and than i store the Datas. I also added a custom exception Handler and send the stacktrace of any crash to my server.
Works perfekt for me